# Python: convert dict of key: list to dict: key/value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Having a hard time wrapping my head around this (overtired):

I have a dict like so:

```
{'FOO': [7, 11], 'BAR': [42, 0]}
```

I need to convert it to be:

```
{'name': 'FOO', 'count1': 7, 'count2': 11}, {'name': 'BAR', 'count1': 42, 'count2': 0}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you need to do a `for` loop over the items in the dict, populating the new list in the manner described. (Also, what you want it converted to is not valid python. Did you mean for it to be in a list?)

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code if you have already attempted it. As already mentioned, you really just need to iterate over the first dict and insert the items into a new list in the correct pattern. It looks to be fairly simple to figure out, maybe try searching around online a bit more and I’m sure you’ll find something similar to what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

One way may be to iterate over dictionary items and again iterate over values:

```
result = []

# for key value in original dictionary
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    # each new inner item will be dictionary as well
    item = {'name': k}
    # iterate through values of the key
    for index, value in enumerate(v, 1):
        item['count{}'.format(index)] = value
    result.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to combine elements from your answer with the dict(zip... line from Ajax1234 to get exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your help.